# jQuery add bottom border to element

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to add a `bottom border` to an element when the user has scrolled after a certain point. For some reason this script is doing nothing. The code is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var posFromTop = $(window).scrollTop();

        if(posFromTop > 515){
            // if more than 200px from the top do something
            $(function(){
                $(".menu").css({ border-bottom: "2px solid #ff4141": });
            });
        } else {
            // otherwise do something else.
            $(function(){
                $(".menu").css({ 'border-bottom', 'none': });
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You don't need to define the CSS transitions inside any functions. They should be inside the if-else block as normal statements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You forgot add appostrofs/quotes on `border-bottom`, or you can use `borderBottom`
- `$(function(){` its shortcut for `$(document).ready(function(){`, so dont use it as wraper
- You can use shorthand of if/else as `( condition ? true : false )` ... or you can cache element to improve performance like this: `$menu = $('.menu')` and then use `$menu.css(...`

**jQuery code:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var posFromTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        $(".menu").css({ 'border-bottom': (posFromTop>515 ? "2px solid #ff4141" : "none") });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use camel case syntax:

```
 $(".menu").css({ borderBottom: "2px solid #ff4141": });
```

Or wrap property in quotes:

```
$(".menu").css({ "border-bottom": "2px solid #ff4141": });
```

And this line is wrong:

```
$(".menu").css({ 'border-bottom', 'none': });
```

Should be:

```
$(".menu").css({ borderBottom : 'none' });
```